# Extract a composition of layouts and data as image

Tags: java, html, css, image

**A bit of context:** I am currently developing a bot for Discord, which is tailored for players of "Path of Exile". One of the functions this bot is planned to have is acquiring the data of items from the inofficial wiki.

**The problem:** On [this sub-page](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Shavronne%27s_Wrappings) you can see a bit of text as well as an "image" on the right side (image below, for those of you who cannot or do not want to access this page). **This image is what I ultimately want to end up with.**

[image: Example of an item "image"]

This is sadly not as easy as it initially seems, as the image - as stated in the title - is not actually an image but rather a composition of a border, and data, which makes the extraction significantly harder.

Here's an example, taken from the html code from the sub-page mentioned above. This is poorly formatted, but it's only supposed to give you a rough overview, as this is not a "Gimme codez"-type of question.

```
<div id="mw-content-text" lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
<p><span class="infobox-page-container">
<span class="item-box -unique">
<span class="header -double">Shavronne's Wrappings
<br />Occultist's Vestment</span><span class="item-stats">
<span class="group"><em class="tc -default">Energy Shield: 
<em class="tc -value"><em class="tc -mod">(336 to 420)</em></em></em 
</span><span class="group"><em class="tc -default">Requires Level <em class="tc -value">62</em>,
<em class="tc -value"><em class="tc -value">180</em></em> Int</em>
</span><span class="group -textwrap tc -mod">3% reduced Movement Speed (Hidden)
<br />(3-10)% increased <a href="/Spell_Damage" title="Spell Damage" class="mw-redirect">
Spell Damage</a></span><span class="group -textwrap tc -mod">
(140-200)% increased <a href="/Energy_Shield" title="Energy Shield" 
class="mw-redirect">Energy Shield</a><br />
10% faster start of <a href="/Energy_Shield" title="Energy Shield" 
class="mw-redirect">Energy Shield</a> Recharge<br />+(30-40)% to 
<a href="/Lightning_Resistance" title="Lightning Resistance" class="mw-redirect">
Lightning Resistance</a><br />Reflects 1 to 250 <a 
href="/Lightning_Damage" title="Lightning Damage" class="mw-redirect">
Lightning Damage</a> to Melee Attackers<br />
<a href="/Chaos_Damage" title="Chaos Damage" class="mw-redirect">
Chaos Damage</a> does not bypass <a href="/Energy_Shield" 
title="Energy Shield" class="mw-redirect">Energy Shield</a></span>
<span class="group -textwrap tc -flavour">Shavronne's apparel became
ever more extravagant<br />as her body and soul became ever more 
corrupted.</span></span><a 
href="/File:Shavronne%27s_Wrappings_inventory_icon.png" 
class="image"><img alt="Shavronne&#39;s Wrappings inventory icon.png" 
src="https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/pathofexile.gamepedia.com
/6/62/Shavronne%27s_Wrappings_inventory_icon.png?version=962a897e10c0d4824545926c2249b5d4" 
width="156" height="234" /></a></span></span>
```

**What have I tried so far:** Nothing, really. I've tried coming up with a way of extracting this image by somehow programmatically taking a screenshot from the website & then cutting out the desired image, but I couldn't find a way of finding that position.

**The question:** What would be a possible approach for getting this data as image?

Comment: Can you look for the position of the orange border, and take a screenshot of just whats inside that? if it's not unique, try finding the CSS class that sets the color of the border and change it to something unique, and then programmatically find that? I'm not super familiar with the capabilities of Java in this regard.

Comment: A quick perusal shows that all the images you are looking for are in the form of `File:*_icon.png`.  Can you get it that way by looking for file names that match that?

Comment: Regarding the `File:*_icon.png`-suggestion: Those images are just the basic item model (as image), without the additional item info. The rest is composed using layouts that I - as far as I can see (probably wrong though) - cannot directly access :/